# C# WMI and SCCM2012

Tags: c#, wmi, sccm

Long story short, I'm coming up with a "dumbed down" SCCM Config Console.
I'm at the point where I'm trying to figure out how to move a computer into a collection. I'm writing this console in C#. I can run scripts within my program, but I don't want to rely on scripts to do the heavy lifting behind the scenes. Problem with this, is there's very sparse information on SCCM and C# for some reason. It's all VBScript and/or Powershell.

So I'm wondering if anyone here has some pointers, examples, reading materials.. anything that can shed some light on what I'm trying to do. I've managed to cobble together bits of code in order to connect to WMI from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj902914.aspx), and that seems to be working as far as I can tell. My program is also pulling live data via SQL, so some information I probably already have (such as the ResourceID, or the NetBIOS name of every computer)

So I can theoretically connect to WMI, what code would I throw at it if I wanted to move RID: 163841 into "Windows 7 Imaging" collection for instance?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**-Edit-** Perhaps I should word it this way:
How would I ...

a) Connect to WMI on SCCM server using C#

b) and then Move a computer into a collection using native code

Links to websites, a key method, code snippets, I'll even take psychic readings at this point.

Comment: do a google search on C# WMI there are actually tons of examples on the internet using WMI with C#

Comment: Have any examples? If I search for this I get a whack of random unhelpful bits of code, half of the time has nothing to do with C#. Nothing that addresses specifically moving collections either. At least so far, research continues.

Comment: can you post what code you have tried so far.. in regards to what you are trying to do..?

Comment: The only code I have as it pertains to WMI is encased in that MSDN link above. I can connect (or at least the code executes without erring out) from there I have no idea what to do. The bulk of the code that I do have is more toward getting info via SQL, and the UI elements.

Comment: For those wondering the same as I, or to those still wondering what it is I'm after, I found an article that is relevant. Executing WMI methods in C#: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/614206/Execute-WMI-method-on-remote-computer   
Still not sure what method I need in order to call, but it's something. In my situation for some reason the server doesn't have a /root/ccm/site_xxx namespace like everything says it should have.

Comment: Sorry, meant /root/sms/site_xxx (/sms doesn't exist)

Comment: Well, I guess I'll pack this one in. Not seeing much in the way of lightbulbs lighting up over people's heads. Further digging, I located the /root/sms namespace. I used CIM Studio to browse /root/sms and found my ./site_xxx namespace. Great. I also found a powershell snippet that nicely gets a list of methods available under that namespace. (http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2012/08/17/how-to-display-all-methods-for-all-classes-in-a-wmi-namespace-using-powershell/)
Then, searching for the method names that looked helpful, I've finally got at least a direction

Comment: (contd.) This looks to be what I'm looking for: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/systemcenter/en-US/be8eaca0-8420-4791-961d-4e17fa61bb3a/sccm-addmembershiprule-with-c
Haven't tried it yet, but it looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to do similar, and are just as lost as I was:
CIMStudio is your friend. I located my /root/sms/site_xxx namespace (it was on a different server).
From there, I ran a powershell snippet (from: http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2012/08/17/how-to-display-all-methods-for-all-classes-in-a-wmi-namespace-using-powershell/) which gives me a list of available methods in that namespace. (In my case I added "-computername NetBIOSofServer" since I'm not local on the server)

I scanned the resulting list, and found a few things that looked helpful. Finally landing on AddMembershipRule (from: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/systemcenter/en-US/be8eaca0-8420-4791-961d-4e17fa61bb3a/sccm-addmembershiprule-with-c)
Now I have some syntax and an idea of how to pull it off.

I haven't followed through yet, but I think this is as good as it gets. 
I hope this helps some poor fellow in the future.

Comment: You probably figured that out but these examples need Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll and AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine.dll which you can get from any SCCM Console installation afaik